# WCF -authenticate client from the digital signature

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, x509certificate, wcf-security

I am new to WCF services, My client wants us to create a service where they can reply for our requests. But they actually want service on Https and authenticate them from the digital signature. They are asking for "cer" file from us.

I really don't know how to produce with this. They provided us system.serviceModel for config file how it should look. Below is the system.serviceModel they provided.

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="WcfServer.Service1">
    <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="abcBinding" contract="WcfServer.IService1" />        
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
      <serviceCredentials>
        <clientCertificate>
          <certificate findValue="xyz.abcdef.com" storeName="TrustedPublisher"
            x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
          <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerOrChainTrust" />
        </clientCertificate>
        <serviceCertificate findValue="localhost" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
      </serviceCredentials>
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="abcBinding" sendTimeout="00:02:00">
      <textMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="64" maxWritePoolSize="16"
        messageVersion="Soap11" writeEncoding="utf-8">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="163840"
          maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="163840" />
      </textMessageEncoding>
      <security allowSerializedSigningTokenOnReply="true" enableUnsecuredResponse="true"
        authenticationMode="MutualCertificateDuplex" requireDerivedKeys="false"
        securityHeaderLayout="Lax" messageProtectionOrder="SignBeforeEncrypt"
        requireSignatureConfirmation="false">
        <secureConversationBootstrap />
      </security>
      <httpsTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
</bindings>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="false" />
```

Please help

Comment: I believe what they are asking for is known as "Mutual Authentication".  You'll want to confirm and then do some homework.  

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733102(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Do you know any example, please send me a link

Comment: Google/Bing - for "wcf setup Mutual Authentication".  Example of results... http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/mutual-certificate-authentication-for-wcf-rest-services